# xml сериализация

Tags: c#, сериализация, передача-данных

как сериализовать объект но не сохранять его а отправить сразу же по сети, как xml файлик?

```
        private async void xmlSerialized(Object obj, string path)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object));

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                // сохраняет файл в Debug а нужно отправить
                serializer.Serialize(fs, obj);
            }
           
          // тут функции для работы с Яндекс диском
 
           // ссылка
           var link = await api.Files.GetUploadLinkAsync("/" + folderName + "/" + xmlFile, overwrite: true);
           
           // в втором аргументе функция принимает сам файл типа fileStream
           await api.Files.UploadAsync(link, fs);
        }
```

Comment: Ну так используйте не `FileStream`, а например `MemoryStream`, будет вам без использования диска, лишь память.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте не `FileStream`, а `MemoryStream`.

```
private async void xmlSerialized(Object obj, string path)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object));

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
    ms.Position = 0;

    var link = await api.Files.GetUploadLinkAsync("/" + folderName + "/" + xmlFile, overwrite: true);
           
    await api.Files.UploadAsync(link, ms);
}
```

И не используйте `async void` - это очень плохая практика.